# Does Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 Standard 5 User CAL include MS Outlook to be installed on clients?

Tags: exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Does Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 Standard 5 User CAL include MS Outlook to be installed on clients? Or I need to purchase also 5 Outlook 2010 licenses?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to purchase outlook separately, or bundled with msoffice. If you don't want to use outlook, there are quite a few free clients available for all the platforms, plus msexchange provides a web gui (OWA)